# Remove USB permission from Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I gave USB access to the extension page, but there is no button like on a normal page to revoke this permission.
How can I do it without reinstalling browser?

Comment: Uninstalling the extension, then installing it again should probably do it. If not I would consider it a bug, which you can report on https://crbug.com.

Comment: Uninstalling does not help. The Only way is to change folder name and rebuild extension again.